# Objective-C #import with concatenating a path prefix

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor

I currently have working a conditional `#import` where:

```
#ifdef MY_IMPORT_PREFIX
#import "MyFramework/MyHeader.h"
#else
#import "MyHeader.h"
#endif
```

Where I define MY_IMPORT_PREFIX in the XCode project as so:
[image: Preprocessor Macros in XCode project]

But I'd like to try to optimize that to a single line where I concatenate the value of MY_IMPORT_PREFIX (often undef but might be defined) to the file I want to import.

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
#define MY_CONCAT_2(c,d) c ## d
#define MY_CONCAT(a,b) MY_CONCAT_2(a,b)

#import MY_CONCAT(MY_IMPORT_PREFIX, MyHeader.h)
```

Anybody up for the challenge?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to shorten what you have to write maybe you could just put the `#ifdef...` lines in a separate header file and then import that file in all sources files where you want to import `MyHeader.h` with a conditional prefix.